# Delete cell from tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, swift3

I am using core data to populate a table view cell. I am trying to implement a function to delete the cell however I keep getting this error

> Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3600.6.21/UITableView.m:1610
>   2017-07-15 22:07:51.077 Annoying Alarm- Alarm can't be snoozed or stopped![7608:793341] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1),

My code for view controller is as follows

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == .delete {

        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! AlarmCell
        let identifier = cell.time.text

        for object in self.controller.fetchedObjects!{
            if object.timeTitle == identifier {
                print("HELLO!")

               print("deep inside if")
               context.delete(object)
                ad.saveContext()
                tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
                //tableView.reloadData()

            }
        }

    }

}
```

The core date part works just fine and when I reopen the app the cell does disappear. My problem is when I actually press delete the

```
tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
```

function throws the error displayed above. When I comment it out, no crash occurs but the cell is not deleted unless I go to another view then come back to this one.

Comment: Do you have an array into which you're putting all of the fetched objects and then reading that array to populate your table?

Comment: If you have an array which you are putting the objects into, you will need to remove that item before you remove the cell from the Tableview

Comment: Are you using NSFetchedResultsController? If so, did you implement the NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate? Within there, you delete the tableView row.

Comment: Why do you use a cumbersome repeat loop and get data from the cell?? The object to be deleted is simply `self.controller.object(at: indexPath)`

Comment: I do no have an array of objects to populate my cells what I do instead is using the NSFetchedResultsController and index path to call a configureCell function

Comment: I am not sure of how to delete the tableView row using NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

error indicates that after deleting the row you should **remove it from your array** and update your array. then you should reload your tableview so your tableviews **numberofrows get updated**.

Comment: I did a fetchrequest afer removing object from array and reloaded the tableview content now it works! no need to implement tableview.deleterows function since I am basically just removing objects from core data fetching the new objects then update the view!